# Spring cannot find class path resource

Tags: spring, maven, classpath, maven-shade-plugin

I googled my problem several times. Some of them was good, but not the solution for my problem. Since now, I took hours, to solve my problem.

I started a project in eclipse using maven.
After that, I added spring and hibernate as dependencies.
This project isnt a normal static void main() project.
It is a plugin, which i can implement in an other running program.

Now let me explain my problem:
When I try to start my plugin (FYI: putted it into /plugins folder of the main program), I get a I/O Exception:

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The applicationContext.xml is in my src/main/resources folder and also in my classpath. I checked it with winRar. After the build process, the applicationContext.xml was in the root directory.
[CLICK TO OPEN THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/capVN.png)

I also use the apache maven-shade-plugin, to include all my dependencys.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <mainClass>com.lostforce.core.LostForceCore</mainClass>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The applicationContext.xml can be found! I checked it with

```
System.out.println("Is null: " + (getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("applicationContext.xml") == null));
```

This returned false for me!

I load the applicationContext.xml with this code:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

I dont know why it happens.
All things I read about this problems, dont work.

My Project:
[CLICK TO OPEN THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdmQN.png)

A little checklist:
 - src/main/resource is in my classpath
 - applicationContext.xml is in the src/main/resource folder
 - build my proect with maven mvn: clean package
 - Use the maven-shade-plugin to include dependencys

Hope anyone can help me. Thank you

Comment: Should be `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/applicationContext.xml")`. Notice the slash.

Comment: Than the output is true

Comment: So it worked, congrats!

Comment: No? :D When the output it true, then the file could not be found

Comment: EDIT:
When I use public static void main(...) then it works. So the problem occures, that I use it as plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem!
Because my project is a plugin, I have to define a other classloader. So I Created this startup Method:

```
public class SpringBootstrap {

private final ClassLoader classLoader = SpringBootstrap.class.getClassLoader();

public ApplicationContext startupSpring() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml") {
        protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
            super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
            reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_NONE);
            reader.setBeanClassLoader(classLoader);
            setClassLoader(classLoader);
        }
    };
    return context;
}
```

}